# Unclear Difference between Phonegap and Apache cordova

Tags: ios, cordova

After reading [this](http://phonegap.com/2012/03/19/phonegap-cordova-and-what%E2%80%99s-in-a-name/) article still i am not clear with Phonegap and Cordova. Some where said that Cordova is an engine which power up the Phonegap (like webkit in browser) My assumption is

1. Phonegap -- Adobe product --> used for taking remote build Apache , Its not open source
2. Cordova -- ASF product --> support only native machine build. (For
   an example if developer using Windows PC. To take build for IOS, he needs to setup Cordova environment in MAC too), but free of cost when moves to production.

Other than this anyother major concepts left. Best answer for this post will improve better understanding on this basic concepts.

http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/guide/cordova what about this one still i am in confused state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PhoneGap is Cordova with some additional tools such as PhoneGap Build (which takes your HTML and packages it into the native installables (APK/IPA/XAP/etc.). Look at docs.phonegap.com and http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.3.0/index.html you'll see they are exactly the same.

Cordova is a bridge between JavaScript and the native hardware. This means you can write a web app which runs on all platforms and uses Cordova to call native hardware calls through an abstract interface (i.e. the Cordova JavaScript library). E.g. I might need to take a photo, save it to the device's storage and then upload it (admittedly, HTML5 supports this out of the box anyway) - but with Cordova I can do this using the same JavaScript code - so much less coding effort.

The difference between a web app you access browsing the web, and a Cordova web app, is the Cordova web app is package into native binaries to imitate a native app (which is accessed through the device's app store and installed/updated like a native app).

Comment: http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/guide/cordova Check this. They gave option to install phonegap or cordova. This means both are same ?

Comment: Yep - it says pretty much the same as what I said; Phonegap _is_ Cordova with some additional tools (which is Phonegap Build). Sencha states to install Phonegap - assuming you will use Phonegap Build to deploy your apps.

I do not use Phonegap Build so do not need it - since Phonegap is Cordova with the inclusion of the Build module, it seems pointless for me to use it when I can use pure Cordova.

If you think you need Phonegap Build to automate the generation of the platform native binaries (APK/IPA/XAP/etc.) then install that - otherwise Cordova will suffice since the core is the same.

Comment: If you install Cordova instead of Phonegap, just make sure to use the keyword `cordova` instead of `phonegap` wherever they reference phonegap since that is the only difference when using the CLI.

Comment: Probably for what you're using, I imagine so. You don't use Phonegap Build by the sounds of it? If so, then yes, you won't get any benefit from one over the other.

Comment: I am using adobe phonegap build (cloud compiler) for my sencha touch application. I need some basic intro about these topics, after reading some blogs i was confused. So only i post this question.

Comment: OK - in that case you require Phonegap. Phonegap IS Cordova (i.e. all the Javascript methods to access native hardware calls like accelerometer/GPS/camera/mic/etc.) PLUS the addition of Phonegap Build - that's all.